# How to create multiple columns based on the unique values in a single column? (presto SQL)

Tags: sql, group-by, presto

I have the following data in the below example.

```
account_id, campaign_objective, campaign_spend, conversions
__________, __________________, ______________, ___________
1,          sales,              100,            25
1,          brand,              50,             25
2,          sales,              80,             12
2,          brand,              60,             12
```

What I would like to do is create one column for each unique campaign_objective and assign it the corresponding spend value.

```
account_id, sales, brand, conversions
__________, _____, _____, ___________
1,          100,   50,    25
2,          80,    60,    12
```

Notice how first, account_id and conversions remain unchanged, they're just consolidated to a single row per account_id but second, each campaign objective receives its own column (sales and brand) and the spend values corresponding to the account_id are entered under the appropriate columns (spend and brand, respectively.)

How can I accomplish this in Presto SQL?

Comment: have you searched for presto and pivot see for example https://docs.treasuredata.com/display/public/PD/SQL+Tips+for+Hive+and+Presto

Comment: @nbk, this looks promising; one complication is that in practice, I don't have two keys but closer to 100-200, so I would need a for loop like concept to iterate through all possible key-value pairs created by the to_map function under the pivot section. And i'm not sure how bridge this gap.

Comment: look where in the query stands unest and use the sample to understand how it works your sample is quite simple to use with unnest

Comment: @jbuddy_13 AFAIK "dynamic" pivot is not supported by presto. You need to specify all columns by hand (or generate query outside of presto).

Comment: @nbk what would be the point of `unnest` here?

Comment: @GuruStron he posts only 2 campain_objectives to have a [mre] and will have much more in the future, so your code will never work if you don't know exactly how many so UNEST is the way to go

Comment: @nbk what and how you want to `unnest` here? To my knowledge `unnest` flattens arrays (elements) into rows, not columns, so I can't see how it can be used here. Can you please post an answer with `unnest`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know all potential objectives in advance you can pivot with grouping by:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(account_id, campaign_objective, campaign_spend, conversions) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'sales', 100,25),
        (1, 'brand', 50,25),
        (2, 'sales', 80,12),
        (2, 'brand', 60,12)
)

-- query
select account_id
    , sum(if(campaign_objective='brand', campaign_spend)) brand
    , sum(if(campaign_objective='sales', campaign_spend)) sales
    , max(conversions) conversions -- or arbitrary(conversions) or min(conversions)
from dataset
group by account_id
```

Output:

| account_id | brand | sales | conversions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 100 | 25 |
| 2 | 60 | 80 | 12 |

Comment: In practice I have a knowable but very large number of unique campaign_objective values. Presto supports Jinja for templating and I'm wondering if I can hack a for loop into my SQL code this way. Any experience here by chance?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 loops are not part of ANSI SQL AFAIK.